# "Server returned HTTP response code: 403" error installing Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, cmd, ant, jenkins-plugins

I'm seeing the below error when I try to install plugins for Jenkins.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\tech>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8081/ install-plugin ant.hpi -deploy -restart

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No X-Jenkins-CLI2-Port among [null, X-Required-Permission, X-Jenkins,
X-You-Are-In-Group, X-Hudson, Content-Length, Expires, X-You-Are-Authenticated-As, X-Permission-Implied-By, Set-Cookie,
Server, X-Content-Type-Options, Date, X-Jenkins-Session, Content-Type]
        at hudson.cli.CLI.getCliTcpPort(CLI.java:290)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:133)
        at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:72)
        at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:474)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:389)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8081/cli
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
                at hudson.cli.FullDuplexHttpStream.<init>(FullDuplexHttpStream.java:78)
                at hudson.cli.CLI.connectViaHttp(CLI.java:163)
                at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:137)
                ... 3 more
```

1. I have installed Jenkins as a Windows Installer
2. Windows service started
3. Then I copied jenkins-cli.jar to the jenkins folder
4. ant.hpi file is located at jenkins folder itself (I also copied to different drive and gave the absolute path during installation)
5. Enter the command to install plugin which resulted in error as shown above

Comment: The error contains `Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8081/cli`. HTTP 403 means [Forbidden](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4). Check the Jenkins logs to determine why the request was rejected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the troubleshooting section of the [CLI documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/#no-x-jenkins-cli2-port):

> Go to Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security and choose "Fixed" or "Random" under TCP port for JNLP agents.

The CLI is disabled by default; you need to enable this TCP port in Jenkins so that CLI clients may connect.

---

Also, assuming that your Jenkins master has access to the internet, you can just specify the [`ant`](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ant) plugin ID on the command line to install the Ant Plugin (and its dependencies!) directly from the Jenkins Update Centre, rather than having to download and specify each of the required .hpi files.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I dont have access to internet since its a server. I tried other suggestions of changing the TCP port to 'Random' and 'Fixed' but I see a different error now as shown below in both cases. I restarted windows service after the changes done to port. 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8081/ install-plugin E:\jenkinshpi\ant.hpi

ERROR: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission
Please suggest some alternatives and i"m completely new to this jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and errors, got it working by this aliasing statement for jenkins-cli

alias jenkins-cli='java -jar /var/lib/jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar -auth admin:admin'

After this aliasing, you can use the commands like:

jenkins-cli help
jenkins-cli who-am-i

and many other commands (listed by help)

In my case here, I had added SSH key for 'admin' user of Jenkins and I had changed its password to 'admin'

Comment: This results in:  Neither -s nor the JENKINS_URL env var is specified.